# A colorful fractal structure on a graph provided by Wilson's algorithm: any explanation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Consider a big finite rescaled piece of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, i.e. consider a unit square with a thick grid. Famous Wilson's method allows to generate a colored spanning tree of such a graph in a uniform way by popping out the cycles: if the mesh-size tends to 0, then the interesting fractal structure occurs: one can read about this in  *R.Lyons, Y. Peres Probability on Trees and Networks*. It is said there, that this fractal structure is not yet explained. Could someone point to me some works connected to this question, if there are any?

Comment: Have you tried contacting Lyons and/or Peres?

Comment: Not yet, I first though about asking in the club.)

Answer (score 5):

Is this the fractal structure you have in mind?

[image: distances spanning tree]

   
<sub>Image from [Russell Lyons' book page](http://mypage.iu.edu/~rdlyons/prbtree/prbtree.html). Figure 4.6 in the book. Caption:

   
"The distances in the tree to the path between opposite
corners in a uniform spanning tree in a 200x200 grid."</sub>

Comment: This fractal can also be built in SimCity 2K.

Comment: Cool! ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is a 3D-picture of distances but already a 2D picture (it's projection) is interesting: the colors are the colors of the cycles that are popped in Wilson's method. I have in mind a picture from the same book, one page before.